# Compiling QEMU for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, qemu

I am compiling Compiling QEMU for ARM. taking into refrence following link :--
http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/06/qemu-for-embedded-systems-development-part-1/

I am using following download :--

http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/qemu/qemu-0.14.0.tar.gz

```
./configure –-target-list=arm-softmmu
$ make
```

Link says :--

You will find two output binaries, `qemu-arm` and `qemu-system-arm`

I `did not get` qemu-arm binary `but` qemu-system-arm is produced.

How to get `qemu-arm` binary ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use a 4.5 years old version of QEMU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the configure command like this:

```
./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu,arm-linux-user
```

As unixsmurf pointed out, you should also use a new version of QEMU.

Comment: Thanks .. but where can i found the documentation about which arguments to be used with qemu configure ?

Comment: "configure --help" will print the arguments it accepts.