# qemu generate qemu-arm and qemu-system-arm

Tags: arm, qemu

I want to generate qemu-arm  to run a binary.
I download qemu source from [github](https://github.com/qemu/qemu), and build it by following its readme, but only qemu-system-arm generated, I donwn't known why

By type ./configure --help, I tried

```
 ./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu --enable-user
```

but the same, no qemu-arm

After searching google,I find the same problem as this one

[Compiling QEMU for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347898/compiling-qemu-for-arm)

when I tried

```
./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu,arm-linux-user
```

an error occur

```
ERROR: Unknown target name 'arm-linux-user'
```

appreciated someone can give some tips

update :I have tried all above  on ubuntu and mac, all the same

Comment: The error message you post is not the one you get from executing that command (although you do get an error message from -target-list instead of --target-list - I have updated the answer in the linked question to fix this).

Comment: @unixsmurf doesn't work， yeah the error message

Answer (score 2):

thank you @unixsmurf

```
./configure --target-list=arm-softmmu,arm-linux-user
```

above command is valid on linux
after looking into code 
https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/251d7e60148599be685c6f9f3921aee38dccef5c/configure#L5463

It is not supported on mac currently

Comment: Yes, this won't work on Mac because the *-linux-user targets are only supported for running a Linux binary of one architecture on a Linux host of a different architecture. You can't use them to run a Linux binary on a Mac.